# Unable to authenticate using spring security.After entering credentials

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm using Spring security 4 for Authentication, 
While i'm able to redirect to login   page but after that  i'm not able to move further, getting error of **This localhost page can’t be found**

Here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
 http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" 
 id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
      <display-name>self-thin-client</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>

        <listener>
            <listener-class>
                org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
            </listener-class>
        </listener>
        <context-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/security.xml</param-value>
        </context-param>
        <filter>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
        </filter>
        <filter-mapping>
            <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
            <url-pattern>/rs/self/*</url-pattern>
        </filter-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>dspature</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>dspature</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/rs/*</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>

        <servlet>
            <servlet-name>Initializer</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>com.store.Initializer</servlet-class>
            <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
        </servlet>
    </web-app>
```

Here is my security.xml

```
    <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd">


        <!-- Spring MVC based authentication, login page etc.  -->
        <http>
            <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
            <form-login login-page="/rs/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                        authentication-failure-url="/login" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
        </http>

        <!-- Declared authentication manager -->
        <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
            <authentication-provider ref="AuthenticationManager" />
        </authentication-manager>

        <!-- Bean implementing AuthenticationProvider of Spring Security -->
        <beans:bean id="AuthenticationManager" class="com.radix.server.login.AuthenticationManager">
        </beans:bean>

    </beans:beans>
```

Here is my html form,

```
 <form method="post" action="/j_spring_security_check" >
    <p>
      <span>Username:</span>
      <input type="text"  name= "j_username" >
    </p>
    <p>
      <span>Password:</span>
      <input type="password"  name= "j_password" >
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </p>
  </form>
```

I think Issue might be with url mapping but i'm not able to figure it out what i did wrong with it,Please help me with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this mapping in `web.xml` this way:

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Otherwise, your `login-processing-url` and others won't match the `FilterChainProxy` url pattern so they won't run properly.

EDIT: To avoid CSRF, try this inside your `<security:http>` element:

`<security:csrf disabled="true"/>`

But, as I said before, setting base path for `springSecurityFilterChain` for such a specific path `/rs/self/*`, I don't think it's a good idea. More specifically, It has no sense at all. According to your `<security:http>` element, it seems you want to protect all url's in app (`<intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>`) but your `springSecurityFilterChain` is only fired for url's matching `/rs/self/*'.

Please try like this:

Web.xml:

```
<filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Security.xml:

```
<http pattern="/rs/login" security="none"/>
<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <form-login login-page="/rs/login" login-processing-url="/j_spring_security_check"
                authentication-failure-url="/login" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>
```

Logout success url does not match login form url, but it seems you want to be the same. If you want this way, change it to `<logout logout-success-url="/rs/login" />`

EDIT2: 
As of your last comments, I think last remaining problem is in the jsp form action. Try changing action this way:

```
<form method="post" action="/your_app_context/j_spring_security_check" >
```

Comment: That has no sense for me. How would login stop working if your first issue for which you posted your question was exactly that login was not working? Actually, reading your config nothing states that `/rs/self` or `/rs` was in fact you context name... and if it is really the app context name, I honestly can't find the sense on the way your are configuring the `security:http` element and it's inner `intercept-url`'s. Lastly, if `rs` or `rs/self` is your application-context/war name, it shouldn't be included in any mapping url you use in `web.xml` nor in `security.xml` nor in any controller.

Comment: I have hard-coded it in jsp form login  /rs/self/j_spring_security_check, If i have to use <form method="post" action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/j_spring_security_check" > instead of <form method="post" action="/rs/self/j_spring_security_check"  >

Comment: this will not able to redirect to the security.xml as filter should be match

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146410/discussion-between-abhijeet-gulve-and-jlumietu).

Comment: Please copy the url of the login page from the browser which does work. And how you think the url would not match the filter mapping? `/*` is an universal matcher for all url below the app context